# Cardinality of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say I have a set $Y$ such that $\vert Y \vert = \aleph_0$ ($Y$ is countable), 
and one $y \in Y$.

How can I prove that $\vert \{ X \in P(Y) \mid y \in X \} \vert = \aleph$ ?
Meaning that the group of all subsets of $Y$ which $y$ is in them is not countable.

Comment: I would ask which $\aleph$ you are talking about, but it is rather well-known that any choice of $\aleph_\alpha$ yields either a false claim or an undecidable statement.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli maybe the intent is to prove it is some $\aleph$! :-)

Comment: Needs a little more context, as above, but then also what you yourself have tried or thought.

Comment: I suspect the intent was to prove that $|\{A\in P(\mathbb N)\mid\{0\}\in A\}| = P(\mathbb N). \qquad$

Comment: All I know is that $\aleph_0$ is countable, and besides that there's only $\aleph$ which is not countable. I tried to show a bijection between this group and $P(Y)$, unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the proof without the restriction that $0 \in A$?  Then take a set in $P(\Bbb N)$ and correspond it to the set with all the elements increased by $1$ and $0$ added in.  This is a bijection between all of $P(\Bbb N)$ and your $A$.

Comment: But that's a bijection between the subsets that has $0$ and the subsets that $0$ doesn't belong to them, not to all $P(N)$, doesn't it?

Comment: No, you start with all of $P(N)$ and finish with those that contain $0$